# Using a function to create dictionaries from text in a list

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary, text

Trying to analyze some data that is coded into a text file. Each line in this text file is a chunk of structured data that contains some information that I need, so I created a function to iterate thru all line and generate a dictionary from it, extracting the data I want and labeling it. But the dictionary I'm creating at the function is not being recognized and display the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "TSE.py", line 43, in <module>
print(dic)
NameError: name 'dic' is not defined
```

My code is this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

with open('/path/to/Documents/Eleicoes 2018/Resultados/new2010.txt') as f:
    df1 = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]

with open('/path/to/Documents/Eleicoes 2018/Resultados/new2012.txt') as f:
    df2 = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]

with open('/path/to/Documents/Eleicoes 2018/Resultados/new2014.txt') as f:
    df3 = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]

with open('/path/to/Documents/Eleicoes 2018/Resultados/new2016.txt') as f:
    df4 = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]

lista = []

def extr(line):
    dic = {}
    dic['Ano'] = line[2]
    dic['Turno'] = line[3]
    dic['UF'] = line[5]
    dic['UE_City_TSE'] = line[6]
    dic['City_TSE'] = line[7]
    dic['Municipio'] = line[8]
    dic['Zona'] = line[9]
    dic['Cargo_Cod'] = line[10]
    dic['Candidato'] = line[14]
    dic['Cargo_Come'] = line[15]
    dic['COD_Apto'] = line[18]
    dic['Apto'] = line[19]
    dic['Situacao_COD'] = line[20]
    dic['Situacao'] = line[21]
    dic['Partido'] = line[23]
    dic['Quantidade_Votos'] = line[28]
    return dic

for i in range(len(df1)):
    x = df1[i].split(';')
    extr(line=x)
    print(dic)
    lista.insert(i,dic)
    continue

print(lista[:5])
```

I know this not be the best way to map this data, but I'm facing a few problems to load this file, and also to use numpy in order to structure it was an array. So despite heuristics, can someone help me with this? When I was not defining a function and only iterating thru line selecting the data I need all the dictionaries were the same, being the last line or the first line. I tried to clean the dictionary after appending the dictionary created at the iterations but all dictionaries were empty when I did this. If you need more explanation or think my heuristic is completely wrong and I should change it, feel welcome to give some advice! Thanks!

Comment: Please read the FAQ on how to make a question, instead you will get down votes. You should preserve the syntax. Did you miss the indent? I suppose the cause of the error is that ‘dic’ variable defined inside the ‘extr’ function scope and doesn’t exist in the usage place. You should write something like this ‘dic = extr(x)’ to fix the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the dictionary is declared inside the function. Hence it is local to that scope and you're not storing the returned value into a variable. Here try this

```
for i in range(len(df1)):
    x = df1[i].split(';')
    dic = extr(line=x)
    print(dic)
    lista.insert(i,dic)
    continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use indenting in Python code.
Replace

```
extr(line=x)
```

with

```
dic = extr(line=x)
```